# how to use select statement with dbGetQuery in Rstudio?

Tags: sql, r, dbi

I have set a connection from R to the oracle database but not able to rectify this error

```
library(RJDBC)
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), "zzz", UID="xyz" , PWD ="xyz" )
z= dbGetQuery(con,"select * from car_price_table where type= 'car' and Date %between% c('2010-01-01', Sys.date()) ")
```

But I am getting this error

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: HY000: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: Amit? Have you seen/tested @Waldi's answer? It resolves your question; if there are still problems, you'll likely get no changes unless you bring them back here. (If not, is there a reason you have not accepted?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly mix `R` syntax with `SQL` syntax.
In particular `%between%` isn't a valid `SQL` statement, hence the `invalid character` error.

You could use `glue` or `paste0` to insert `R` values in `SQL` code :

```
qry <- glue::glue("
SELECT * FROM car_price_table
WHERE type= 'car' 
AND Date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '{Sys.Date()}'")

qry
SELECT * FROM car_price_table
WHERE type= 'car' 
AND Date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2021-03-22'
                 
result = dbGetQuery(con,qry)
```

Also using `Date` as field name might be risky because `DATE` is a reserved keyword.